# changes to JS file not reflected in VS2012 build in ASP MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

This has happened a few times already and it's pretty frustrating.

I make some changes to one of my Javascript files. Then I save the changes and proceed to test the build in IE.

All my changes are not reflected in the `dynamic` version of the file.

So far, I have fixed the problem by changing the file name and reincluding it in my bundle.

(The MS forums only tell me that I might be editing a wrong version of the file, which is not the case. See above.)

I am new to Windows so I figure there might be something I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Append a Guid parameter after the script file name.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution: [Force reload of JS and CSS files with ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2011/12/force-reload-of-js-and-css-files-with.html).